# How to align image and title and text next to it?

Tags: html, css

I want to align images on left and `<h>` and `<p>` text on right next to it like this:

[image]

What is the best way to do this so it will work best for responsive design as well ?

http://jsfiddle.net/kfV7F/

Answer (score 3):

```
img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px border:1px solid;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:left;
}
span:after {
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfV7F/1/)

after **text** you must clear `float`

Comment: I was adding a `div` wrap, but this is cleaner. Nice! Just be careful if this is used in a multi-column layout. I've run into problems with the clearing trying to interact with other columns.

Comment: @bugaloo With this the 2nd and 3rd title are not on top in line with the image, as on 1st image. How come?

Comment: This occurs because the text will no white space.
I edited it here http://jsfiddle.net/kfV7F/3/

Comment: Your latest jsfiddle is same as the other one.

Comment: You can also add this style `span { word-wrap: break-word; }`